# php switch based off of folder domain name

Tags: php

Is it possible to have one php page that uses a switch to show a certain image based off a subdomain that accessed that page? For example, www.mysite.com/example1 would show example1.jpg, whereas www.mysite.com/example2 would show example2.jpg? I have a print form that I would like to have someone be able to print from the page but there are over 50 different subfolder names that are used in our offline url's.

Hope this makes sense and something like a switch could do the trick with this.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, all you need to do is parse out the request URI, depending on whether or not its gonna have more information. but you could have this

`<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>.jpg" />`

in its simplest form. Havent tested, but i think this is right

if you want it more complicated, you could do something like this

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$img = 'example1.jpg';
switch($url)
{
    default:
    case 'example1':
        break;
    case 'example2':
        $img = 'example2.jpg';
        break
    // other cases
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $img?>" />
```

Comment: the other two answers might not work if you are using a front controller, (everything goes through a index.php or something)

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] would be something like example.html, no? So your src would be equal to `example.html.jpg`

Comment: OP didnt say `www.mysite.com/example1.html`, so im making the assumption that its not that. if it is, its rather easy to parse it out, or to include it in the case

Answer (score 0):

You'd parse the url for the current page and then display the pic you want (given that all the pics live in the same directory).

So:

```
$parsed=parse_url($url);
$fn=basename($parsed['path'],'.php'); //given that all your pages are .php pages
$img= $path_to_images . $fn.'.jpg';

echo "<img src='$img'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`.
it contains the self link. All you need to do is to build a function that removes the undesired content (in this case http://www.mysite.com/) and uses what comes next.
Example:

```
<?php
     function removeDomain($strDomain){
         //Divide the string into pieces separated by "/";
         $domain = explode("/", $strDomain);
         //Unset http: and the domain name
         unset($domain[0], $domain[1], $domain[2]);
         //put together whatever is after the domain name.
         return implode("/", $domain);
     }
     echo removeDomain($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
```